# Dll whose reference was removed from an asp.net core web api project disturbing published projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I referenced NetSpell in another DLL project being referenced in a WebAPI project. I later removed the NetSpell. To my chagrin, when I published and deployed the WebApi, it keeps looking for the NetSpell assembly.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Great use of the word chagrin.

Comment: Is it referenced somewhere in any of the projects? You could search all files (Ctrl+Shift+F) for 'NetSpell' and see if it's somewhere